# How to get JSON when decoder fails to unmarshal?

Tags: json, go

I am using a `json.Decoder` to decode JSON delivered over a network stream. It works fine, but whenever someone sends data that doesn't fit the schema (e.g. sending a negative integer when the struct's field type is unsigned) it returns an error with a vague message that doesn't pinpoint the offending property. This makes debugging more difficult.

Is there any way to extract the JSON that the decoder was trying to unmarshal when it errored? Here's a small reproducable snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    buff := bytes.NewBufferString("{\"bar\": -123}")
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(buff)

    var foo struct{
        Bar uint32
    }
    if err := decoder.Decode(&foo); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("TODO: how to get JSON that caused this error?")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(foo.Bar)
    }
}
```

Or on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/-WdYBkYEzJ

Comment: Does `Bar` have to be a `uint32`? Is there a reason you couldn't make that an `int`?

Comment: Have you tried [json.Decoder.Buffered](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Buffered) or [json.Decoder.Token](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token)?

Comment: This is another example of why you should not use unsigned values for anything that could possibly be negative, even when a negative value is incorrect. Use an int, int32, or int64 and validate the "schema" another way.

Comment: @JimB It is `uint32` because negative values aren't valid inputs. I _want_ the unmarshalling to error because it should; the data is not valid. I just want it to be specific about where it failed so I can log meaningful data for debugging. Your solution would indeed work in the example I gave; but what if the JSON property is a string/array/object instead of an int?

Comment: Negative values may not be valid for *your* schema, but they *are* valid json numbers. Unsigned values should be reserved for bitwise or modulo operations, otherwise used signed values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Go 1.8 this is now possible. The `UnmarshalTypeError` type now contains `Struct` and `Field` values which provide the name of the struct and field which caused a type mismatch.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    buff := bytes.NewBufferString("{\"bar\": -123}")
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(buff)

    var foo struct{
        Bar uint32
    }
    if err := decoder.Decode(&foo); err != nil {
        if terr, ok := err.(*json.UnmarshalTypeError); ok {
                fmt.Printf("Failed to unmarshal field %s \n", terr.Field)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println(foo.Bar)
    }
}
```

The error message string also was changed to contain this new information.

Go 1.8:

```
json: cannot unmarshal number -123 into Go struct field .Bar of type uint32
```

Go 1.7 and earlier:

```
json: cannot unmarshal number -123 into Go value of type uint32
```

Answer (score 2):

Some information is in the error, which is of type [`*json.UnamrshalTypeError`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#UnmarshalTypeError)

```
type UnmarshalTypeError struct {
        Value  string       // description of JSON value - "bool", "array", "number -5"
        Type   reflect.Type // type of Go value it could not be assigned to
        Offset int64        // error occurred after reading Offset bytes
}
```

You can get the offset in the json string, the `reflect.Type` of the field being unmarshaled into, and the json description of the Value. This can still pose a problem for types that implement their own unmarshaling logic, which is referenced by [issue 11858](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11858)

Answer (score 0):

You can get at each element, key, value, and even delimiters using `decode.Token()` such as this in [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Xp-TWF-lJH), and below (modified from your example):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    buff := bytes.NewBufferString(`{"foo": 123, "bar": -123, "baz": "123"}`)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(buff)

    for {
        t, err := decoder.Token()
        if _, ok := t.(json.Delim); ok {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("type:%11T | value:%5v //", t, t)

        switch t.(type) {
        case uint32:
            fmt.Println("you don't see any uints")
        case int:
            fmt.Println("you don't see any ints")
        case string:
            fmt.Println("handle strings as you will")
        case float64:
            fmt.Println("handle numbers as you will")
        }

        if !decoder.More() {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

This will output

```
type:     string | value:  foo //handle strings as you will
type:    float64 | value:  123 //handle numbers as you will
type:     string | value:  bar //handle strings as you will
type:    float64 | value: -123 //handle numbers as you will
type:     string | value:  baz //handle strings as you will
type:     string | value:  123 //handle strings as you will
```

You can switch on the type and handle each one as you wish. I have shown a simple example of that as well, each of the "//comments" in the result are conditional based on the type.

You'll also notice that each numbers' type is float64, although they would fit into an int, or even uint in the case of the "foo" value, and I check for those types in the switch but they never get used. You would have to provide your own logic in order to convert the float64 values to the types you wanted if they could be and handle types that wouldn't convert as special cases, or errors or whatever you wanted.